# Loading library on each map() execution

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spacy

Library called [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) has some problems when being shared across executors ([problem with pickling](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1270)). One of the workarounds is to import it independently on each map execution but the load takes a while.

I'm new to Spark and so I don't understand what's the exact mechanism behind `map`. What will happen in example case below?

I'm afraid of the worst case scenario, where individual lines of text are processed independently and for each one it will import spacy. Fresh import can take good 10+ s and we have 1,000,000+ lines of text.

```
class SpacyMagic(object):
    _spacys = {}

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, lang):
        if lang not in cls._spacys:
            import spacy
            cls._spacys[lang] = spacy.load(lang)
        return cls._spacys[lang]


def run_spacy(sent):
    nlp = SpacyMagic.get('en')
    return [wrd.text for wrd in nlp(sent)]

sc = SparkContext(appName="LineTokenizer")
data = sc.textFile(s3in)
res = data.map(process_line)
print res.take(100)
sc.stop()
```

Comment: I've tested and it seems that `spacy` is called only once. Or at least very infrequently.

Comment: map "maps (or applies) a function" over all elements... Over all executors...  instead of serializing the data using pickle

Comment: @cricket_007 right, but is the data sent "one at a time" or some arbitrary size batches, or the biggest batch it can do? How can I control/know how data is divided into nodes?

Comment: In HDFS, you need to understand how datanodes store blocks and what classifies as an InputSplit. If you are using any other filesystem, I think the InputSplits are still managed by Spark, but I don't know how sizes are controlled. For a `textFile`, lines are sent one at a time in an RDD, but in Hadoop block sizes of 64 or 128 MB (whatever default of the cluster is)